# Exercise of spaces path connected

Tags: general-topology, connectedness, path-connected

The exercise says: Let $X$ be a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$ given by points with at least one irrational coordinate. Show that $X$ is path connected.

Comment: $(\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q)\times\mathbb Q$ is not path connected, but $\mathbb R^2\setminus (\mathbb Q^2)$ is path connected.

Comment: Sorry, I committed a mistake. The exercise says: Let X be a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$ given by points with at least one irrational coordinate. Show that X is path connected.

Comment: Hmm. Can $A\times B$ be connected if $B$ is not connected?

Comment: Yes it can be possible

Comment: Maybe you can edit your question then.

Comment: Can you write your space $X$ in a a form like $\mathbb R^2 \backslash ???$

Comment: Please clarify your question. The set you have described is usually interpreted as the first set in @CheerfulParsnip's comment and it not connected.

Comment: @Giusy, if your problem was about $X$, the space of points with at least one irrational coordinate, then $X=\mathbb{R}^2\setminus \mathbb{Q}^2$. You should edit that in your question.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** Let $\pi(x,y)=y$. How connected is $\pi\bigl((\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q)\times\mathbb Q\bigr)$?

Comment: Sorry, I committed a mistake. The exercise says: Let X be a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$ given by points with at least one irrational coordinate. Show that X is path connected.

Comment: Then post that question as a new one.

Answer (score 1):

Of all lines through $a\in X$, only countably hit a rational point. Hence for given $a,b\in X$ we can certainly find non-parallel $X$-avoiding lines through them.

Answer (score 0):

Let's fix an element in $X$. I am going to choose a point with both coordinates being irrational, for instance $(w,w)\in X$ with $w=\sqrt{2}$.

To prove that $X$ is path connected is enough to prove that for any point $(a,b)\in X$ we can find a path inside $X$ connecting $(a,b)$ to $(w,w)$. Let's prove it

Let $(a,b)\in X$. WLOG say $a$ is irrational. Then go from $(a,b)$ to $(a,w)$ vertically and then go from $(a,w)$ to $(w,w)$ horizontally. Note that this is a path inside $X$ connecting $(a,b)$ and $(w,w)$.

So we are done.